# P&T List: Information wrapped in quotes dropped on save

Tags: fieldtype

We are using P&T List for one of our channels. On save, all content wrapped in quotes is dropped.

So:

> "I like beautiful melodies telling me terrible things." ― Tom Waits

is saved as:

> — Tom Waits

Of note, placing a space before and after the quote mark keeps the full text, so:

> Clear the thistles and brambles, Whistle " Didn't He Ramble "

...will save as entered.

This is an issue especially since we are looking to enter dimensions in the P&T list field (like 3" x 4.25")

Of note, the issue appears intermittently, deleting content between quotation marks on roughly 80-85% of the saved entries, but leaving a lucky few to survive. As of yet, we haven't been able predict which ones are saved.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the GitHub version of the [**Pixel & Tonic List field**](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/pt_list/) which should fix this issue for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix this issue. We're still getting dropped content. The GitHub version also versions at the same 1.0.3 which is the same as the release version at P&T -- could be different code, of course, but the config file is the same.

Comment: Have you had luck fixing this issue using the GitHub 1.0.3 vs. the P&T download off the Dive Bar? For what it's worth, on our side with both versions, it's oddly intermittent. Happens about 80% of the time with the occasional double quote going through unharmed.

Comment: I just found posts on the P&T support page that were sending people to grab that file when they were having this happen. Looks like they updated the file on the main site to match. Can you edit you question with the new information about this happening intermittently? That's good for people to know.

Comment: Good call. Thanks for the original tip, too.

Comment: Something to test that might explain the intermittent nature of this issue is the types of quotes... is it possible curly quotes copied from a Word Doc are failing while straight quotes are not?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All are typed directly and straight quotes.